# weird data in comma separated .txt file sent by email

Tags: php

I have a simple form, when data is submitted an email is sent with a .txt file attached. The .txt has the data submitted separated by commas.

When some input is such:

- ínput

I get in the .txt file attached in the email:

- Ãnput

This is my code:

```
$to = "hugorod@hugorod.es";
$from = "hugorodadmin@hugorod.es";
$subject = "Subject";
$message = "<p>Please see the attachment.</p>";
$separator = md5(time());
$eol = PHP_EOL;
$filename = date('d.m.y-H:i:s') . "_". $_POST['fName'] . "_" . $_POST['gName'] . ".txt";
$data = $_POST['fName'] . ',' . $_POST['gName'] ."\n";
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
$headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol; 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol;
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";
$body = "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol;
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $message.$eol;
// attachment
$body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $attachment.$eol;
$body .= "--".$separator."--";
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

I show $data and its correct, I guess the problem is when variables are encoded.

Answer (score 0):

You're using ISO-8859-1 encoding, try UTF8 instead.

You can use `utf8_encode()` to encode text from ISO-8859-1 to UTF8 ([PHP Manual utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php))

Alternatively, change the charset of your email.